# Converting a ruby on rails app from sqlite to postgresql

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, thinking-sphinx

I am going to use thinking sphinx for my application and it requires a conversion to postgresql. I have downloaded both sphinx and postgresql using homebrew, but I am unsure how to convert the rest of the application. I do not care about saving my data, as I only have about 5 records in my database. If there is a step by step guide, or a resource that could guide me I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the following video from Peter Cooper to figure out what I was doing wrong. If anyone needs to set up Postgresql in the future reference this: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pf5jPUJAeU4

Answer (score 5):

It's a very simple process if you have stuck to using activerecord and not used any custom SQL.

All you'll need to do is change your gemfile to include `gem 'pg'` and change the database.yml file to have something like the following:

```
  development:
    adapter: postgresql
    database: example_development
    username: postgres
    password: secret
    host: localhost
    encoding: UTF8
```

If you have used custom SQL, you'll just need to convert it to PostgreSQL, which shouldn't be too tricky as it's very similar.

Comment: What about the database line, what do I write for that?

Comment: drop your existing database and recreate it (using rake db commands) after making changes as suggested by Simon.

Comment: I keep getting password errors, which doesn't make sense to me as I am providing the correct password to sign in to postgresql. I created a new app using postgresql on my system and it ran perfectly.  I looked at the database.yml file and it was slightly different than the one provided, copied that format and it still didnt work. Any suggestions?

Comment: I've updated the example above to include the exact things you'll need to provide. Are you sure you can access login to psql with the exact same `username` and `password` settings as the yml file has?

Answer (score 1):

http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/database#common_issues_migrating_to_postgresql